# Will an empty Vec which is never used still be allocated?

Tags: rust, vector, allocation

I have a program where I have a lot of struct types which have a `Vec` as a field, but in most cases the `Vec` never get's used (the types are in a separate library which doesn't know in advance which of types library users will want to add `Vec`s to). The example below illustrates the situation. I want to know whether the empty Vec in `b` will be allocated, or if the compiler is smart enough to know it doesn't get used so doesn't need an allocation. I suspect it will still be allocated, in which case I will wrap the `Vec` in an `Option` so that b can be created without needing to allocate a `Vec`, thereby avoiding many unnecessary allocations.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    message: String,
    vec: Vec<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let a = Foo {
        message: "Hello".to_string(),
        vec: Vec::new(),
    };
    dbg!(a.message);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is likely not smart enough to eliminate the `Vec`, but it still won't allocate as [`Vec::new()` does not allocate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.new):

> The vector will not allocate until elements are pushed onto it.

Answer (score 0):

The `vec` field will still be present in `Foo`, and so it will take 24 bytes there (for the size of the `Vec` struct itself). But it won't allocate any more memory than that since [`Vec::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.new) doesn't allocate.

Using `vec: Option<Vec>` won't use more space than a plain `Vec` even though the compiler will need to store the discriminant because [`Vec` guarantees that its pointer will never be null](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees) (although it may point to a bogus address), so the compiler can use a null pointer to indicate the `None` variant. It *will* however add overhead everywhere when you need to check if `vec` is `None` or contains a vector.

(All sizes assume a 64-bits machine).

Comment: `Option<Vec>` won't add size overhead because `Vec` is null pointer optimized (and [guaranteed to be](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees)), but it will add overhead when checking for `None`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman good point, I wasn't sure about that. Edited my answer.