# Use `Option` to maybe allocate?

Tags: rust

Does this code avoid allocation if it's not needed (based on some runtime predicate)? Or does `Option<Vec<T>>` always result in an allocation?

```rust
let mut x: Option<Vec<u32>> = None;
if predicate {
    x = Some(vec!(1,2,3));
}
```

On the other hand, is this use of `Option` unnecessary due to optimizations meaning empty `Vec`s don't result in allocations anyway?

Comment: Option<Vec> is micro opti by compiler it's a transparent with Vec, so it's really up to your style of code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Rust, an `Option<Vec<T>>` is not going to allocate memory until and unless it is actually used and contains some elements. When you declare a variable of type `Option<Vec<T>>` and set it to `None`, it does not allocate memory for the `Vec`. It only consumes the memory needed to store the Option itself, which has space for the None variant. When it's set to Some(vec), only then will it allocate the memory required for the `Vec`.

So, to answer your first question, the `Option<Vec<T>>` in your code will not allocate memory until the predicate is true and the Some(`vec![1, 2, 3]`) branch is taken.

For your second question, an empty Vec does not allocate. A Vec in Rust has a capacity, which is the amount of space allocated for any future elements, and a length, which is the number of actual elements. If you create a Vec and don't add any elements to it, its length is 0 and so is its capacity, and thus it doesn't allocate any memory for the elements.

So you can actually use an empty Vec to avoid unnecessary memory allocation if you are sure that your Vec will be empty when the predicate is false. Here's how you could do it,

```
let mut x: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
if predicate {
    x = vec![1,2,3];
}
```

This will not allocate memory for the `Vec` until the predicate is `true`. But it is different semantically because None and an empty vector are not the same. If the distinction between no value (None) and an `empty` value `(Vec::new())` is important in your context, you should keep using `Option<Vec<T>>` Otherwise, you can use `Vec<T>` directly.

Answer (score 2):

The allocation is done in the code that the `vec![<elements>]` macro generates, so yes.

You can reduce allocations when you already know how much elements you will write to the vector with [`Vec::with_capacity()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.capacity)

> On the other hand, is this use of `Option` unnecessary due to optimizations meaning empty `Vec`s don't result in allocations anyway?

[Will an empty Vec which is never used still be allocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171712/will-an-empty-vec-which-is-never-used-still-be-allocated)